# No host binding

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, coreos

I do have setup a CoreOS single-node cluster and can access the API from my client without any issues. I did follow the [guide](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/tree/master/single-node). All deployed pods are running fine, and I can access those on the node without problem.

Now I am trying to establish the connection from the outside world using Nginx-Ingress. The service/endpoint is in nginx (figured out via the flag --v=2), but unfortunatly not attached to the node IP. `kubectl get ing` shows the node IP, but the port(s) are not attached to the node, and therefor I cannot access the endpoint/service from the outside world.

I tried to specify `type: NodePort` on the corresponding services, but this does not seem to work. Furthermore the setting `hostNetwork: true` on the ingress-controller RC, but this is not working as well.

**-- Update Start --**

Just tried to use a service in front of the ingress controller RC. This service is of type NodePort. Still the problem exists, the ports are not open on the node, but in the cluster IP range as well as in the Service IP range.

Does this hint to a network problem? IPTables? unsure.

**-- Update End --**

So, how can I access my services from the outside world on this single-node cluster? Any help is appreciated.

**-- Update --**

Added the `--hostname-override=EXTERNAL-IP` to the `kube-proxy yaml`, the service (10.3.0.186) is reachable, the endpoint (10.2.9.8:8080) is reachable from the node, the following iptables entries are present:

```
-A KUBE-SEP-VN7N5XLSTJBPYG7C -s 10.2.9.8/32 -m comment --comment "default/echoheaders:http" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-VN7N5XLSTJBPYG7C -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/echoheaders:http" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.2.9.8:8080
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.3.0.186/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/echoheaders:http cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-SVC-P5R2U4YB6QJZHBET  
-A KUBE-SVC-P5R2U4YB6QJZHBET -m comment --comment "default/echoheaders:http" -j KUBE-SEP-VN7N5XLSTJBPYG7C
```

**-- Update end --**

Comment: I've used the much simpler traefik ingress controller. It runs as POD. https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/

Comment: Hm, would like to stay with nginx, since it supportes kube-lego ;--)

Comment: Try following the README here https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example This should set up the controller and sample services for you. I also wrote an article about it here which may be helpful https://medium.com/@rothgar/exposing-services-using-ingress-with-on-prem-kubernetes-clusters-f413d87b6d34#.qb799dmr0 The examples I used in my article are for traefik but the nginx controller works identically